# Pandas read df randomly

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

i recently tried this multiple classification problem on Kaggle
and these are the `value_counts()` for the labels:

```
2     1661772
4     1613640
8     1471098
5     1389385
9     1361200
3     1337218
7     1325075
6     1316784
10    1250655
1     1240152
0     1240152
```

Now, i know that it isn't balanced, so first of all i need to know how to balance it

I also need to read the file in chunks because i have only 16 GB of memory, and it isn't enough
so i used:

```
data_chunks = pd.read_csv(filename, chunk_size=1024)
data = next(iter(data_chunks))
```

and the variable `data` contains 1024 elements, and all the labels are zeros, which poses a serious threat to zero because my model just trains to return zero for everything
So i need to know how to randomize the selection of chunks in the `read_csv()`  function

Thanks in Advance

PS: i have just started with real life datasets instead of toy ones on `scikit-learn`, and if i've made any rookie mistake, then please excuse me

Comment: Not a `machine-learning` or `artificial-intelligence` question - kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).

Comment: oh... i'm so sorry i got confused with all those jargons and

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hey you can use sample(frac = 0.20) 
this will fetch random 20% data from your csv, you can adjust accordingly

```
data_chunks = pd.read_csv(filename).sample(frac = 0.20)
```

Comment: Okay, but how do i ensure that when i run it again, to get the next 20% of the data, i won't get the same data again?

Answer (score 1):

```
data_chunks = pd.read_csv(filename, chunk_size=1024)
for chunk in data_chunks:
    process(chunk)
```

By doing that you can access all the chunks , now there are multiple ways you can select a balanced class data set by creating a new dataframe with all equal classes udint the chunks. 
 
Also I would recommend using [DASK](https://examples.dask.org/dataframes/01-data-access.html) for large dataframes which cannot be directly loaded into memory. It does not change pandas syntax and works like a charm on large dataframes !

Comment: Thanks, I''ll try that, and surely check out DASK